# How can I activate Collapse Menu in WordPress?

Tags: admin

Inside the WordPress admin dashboard there is a button for making the left side menu collapse (to show just icons and not the icons + text on left side). How can I add jQuery so that it gets automatically collapsed once my plugin opens up. I tried this but it didn't work for me. I want to give a sort of 'full screen' option inside dashboard. Can anyone help me on this?

I tried adding this jquery script to make it work, but it didn't work for me:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery("#collapse-menu").click();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to trigger the click event. Try,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery("#collapse-menu").trigger('click'); });
```

**Update:**
Use the following code to check if menu is already folded, if not trigger click event to fold it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if ( !$(document.body).hasClass('folded') ) {
        jQuery("#collapse-menu").trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Comment: Great it works thanks, can I make it some way like this
that it always make it trigger to full screen,

rite now when i do refresh the click action again happens because of trigger and the menu come back to uncollapse mode

Comment: Updated the answer and added the check. Try it out.

Answer (score 1):

None of that worked for me. I had to use `jQuery(document.body).addClass('folded');`
Wordpress jQuery didnt like `$(document.body).hasClass('folded')`, I had to modify.
Snippet below.

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if ( !jQuery(document.body).hasClass('folded') ) {
        jQuery(document.body).addClass('folded');
    }
    });
```